# Extracting Username\password from text\properties file in VBScript

Tags: sql-server, file, text, vbscript

I am trying to extract the values of fields like Username,password,sqlServer etc from a properties file. It can be read similar to a text file.
The format of the file is as follows: 
    ...

```
abcd.driverClassName=net.xyz.qwer.abcd.Driver
abcd.url=abcd:pqrs:sqlserver:sa
...

abcd.Username=Anant
abcd.Password=Password
```

So I basically used the **InStr()** function to find the position of Filed (Eg. Username). then skipped the position to where the actual password starts, and read it into a variable untill i found a newline chracter.

Following is the sample code:

```
...

Posusername = instr(1,strFile,"username",vbTextCompare)
'Wscript.Echo "Position of Username is: "&Posusername
Set ObjFile = ObjFso.openTextFile(StrFileName)
Objfile.skip(posusername-1)
Objfile.skip(9) 
    Do until objFile.AtEndOfLine
    Username = ObjFile.Readline
Loop
ObjFile.close
...
```

Now this code is working fine while extracting sqlServer, password etc, But surprisingly for Username.. It simply stores the next line i.e. *abcd.Password=Password* in variable **username**
What could possibly be going wrong? Please help!

**Alternate Method**:

```
Do Until oTS.AtEndOfStream
sLine =Trim( oTS.ReadLine )
if "" <> sLine Then
    If "abcd.user" = Left(Trim(sLine), 9 ) Then
        username1=Split(sline,"=")
        Exit Do
    end if
end if
loop
username=Trim(username1(1))
msgbox "Username - " & username
```

This method is working fine. But this only applicable if i know the exact structure of file. What if there are some changes in the files I am reading?

Comment: Some other logic or codes to extract the info is same way are also welcome

Answer (score 0):

Use `regexp`:

```
Function testRegexP(strFile, FieldName)
    Set re = New RegExp
    re.Pattern = "\." + FieldName + "="
    Set matches = re.Execute(strFile)
    If matches.Count > 0 Then
        Set match = matches(0)
        msg = "Found match """ & match.Value & _
              """ at position " & match.FirstIndex & vbCRLF
        msgbox msg
        testRegexP = match 
    Else
        msgbox "No match"
        testRegexP = "Nothing"
    End If
End Function
```

`FieldName` is the field which you're trying to find; e.g. "Username". You can iterate over a list of fields which you want to find and apply the function for each:

```
Dim upBound = 5
Dim fieldList(5)
fieldList(0) = "Username"
fieldList(1) = "Password"
fieldList(2) = "IP"
For i = 0 to ( upBound - 1 ) Step 1
    testRegexP(strFile, fieldList(i))
Next
```

**EDIT 1:**

If you want to store found values with their key, you can use dictionary; define a dictionary like this in the main code:

```
Dim fieldDic 
Set fieldDic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
```

You should also change the `For` statement as below to store returned values from function `testRegexP`:

```
Dim x
Dim fx 
For i = 0 to ( upBound - 1 ) Step 1
    x = fieldList(i)
    fx = testRegexP(strFile, x)
    fieldDic.Add x, fx
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for this, But How can i store the values of these fileds in a perticular variable, eg. Value of USERNAME should be stored in a variable Dim Username. PS, I am new to VbScripting

Comment: Review my answer @Anantvaibhav.

Comment: An error is popping "Class not defined: 'list'. Is there some declaration?

Comment: Sorry @Anantvaibhav, I was a little misunderstood about your issue; I have updated the whole answer. Please review.

Comment: The new code Is error less @Zeinab , But when I am echoing the FieldDic, ablank Msg box pops up, It means values in this FiledDic(0), FiledDic(1), FiledDic(2) is blank. See I have the positions of the fileds i want to find.They are absolutely correct. But how do i grab what is written in front of that field? The Structure of file is exactly  as shown in the question

Comment: Please check out my "alternate method" in edit, which is grabbing the correct result

Comment: In My previous method, after i get the position from **inStr()** , I read the line untill *endOfLine* is found. But in this file the lines are not not ended with typical EndOfLine ('\n') It is something else How can I know which character is it (vbCr,vbCrLf,vbLF,vbNewline)?? Is there a way to find which white space is it?

Comment: @Anantvaibhav, maybe using a temp variable can solve the issue you have faced with my solution. Please checkout my edited answer. BTW, if you want to get all items in the dictionary you should echo `fieldDic.Items`.

Comment: The echo of FieldDic.Items is still empty. Thanks a lot though!